# Deployment error in Python-Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

when i deployed the demo application of python in Google App engine,it works well in local host,when i am deploying the got the error,i also changed proxy_rdns=True,but it does not work,help me to solve.

```
File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\httplib2\httplib2\__init__.py", line 1275, in _conn_request
    raise ServerNotFoundError("Unable to find the server at %s" % conn.host)
httplib2.ServerNotFoundError: Unable to find the server at appengine.google.com
2016-06-24 11:15:08 (Process exited with code 1)
```

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete, and verifiable example.  If this problem is with the GAE demo app, then something else must be going on and we'll need more information.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the command you used to deploy the application? how can you expect the community to help if you don't provide us with a complete traceback of your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today, when trying to run `appcfg.py` to deploy my app to appengine

I then downgraded my google epp engine sdk from 1.9.40 to 1.9.37, rerun, everything was Ok (note that I am using app engine sdk for ubuntu)

So you may try to upgrade/downgrade your version and check status again

hope this helps you